# Is it possible to set workspace-level compiler flags in CodeBlocks?

Tags: codeblocks

I would like to be able to set a compiler flag, for example `-O3`, which applies to all projects within a CodeBlocks workspace.

It needs to be at the workspace level, and not set in CodeBlocks itself, as the flags need to be under version control and shared with colleagues.

Is this possible, if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build options cannot be defined at workspace level. 
 The workspace file is simply a collection of projects and all options must be defined at the individual project level(*.cbp file). For more informations see [CodeBlocks Workspace file](https://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Workspace_file).